# Crashes on Splash Screen throwing java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

According to Playstore ANR & Crashes the app is throwing null pointer on SplashScreen. I've checked the functioning and it looks good at my end. Not all phones are crashing however are.

ActivitySplash.java

```
public class ActivitySplash extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String TAG = "SplashActivity";
    Call<CallbackConfig> callbackConfigCall = null;
    Call<CallbackCategory> callbackLabelCall = null;
    UtilityAdsManager utilityAdsManager;
    PreferenceShared preferenceShared;
    PreferenceAds preferenceAds;
    App app;
    Blog blog;
    Ads ads;
    List<Category> labels = new ArrayList<>();
    DatabaseCategory databaseCategory;
    ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        UtilityGlobal.getTheme(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        imageView = findViewById(R.id.idImageViewSplash);

        databaseCategory = new DatabaseCategory(this);
        utilityAdsManager = new UtilityAdsManager(this);

        preferenceShared = new PreferenceShared(this);
        if (preferenceShared.getThemeIsDark()) {
            UtilityGlobal.themeDarkNavigation(this);
        } else {
            UtilityGlobal.themeLightNavigation(this);
        }

        preferenceAds = new PreferenceAds(this);
        if (preferenceAds.getAdStatus().equals(AD_STATUS_ON)) {
            Application application = getApplication();
            if (preferenceAds.getAdType().equals(ADMOB)) {
                if (!preferenceAds.getAdMobAppOpenAdId().equals("0")) {
                    ((MyApplication) application).showAdIfAvailable(ActivitySplash.this, this::runRequestAPI);
                } else {
                    runRequestAPI();
                }
            } else if (preferenceAds.getAdType().equals(GOOGLE_AD_MANAGER)) {
                if (!preferenceAds.getAdManagerAppOpenAdId().equals("0")) {
                    ((MyApplication) application).showAdIfAvailable(ActivitySplash.this, this::runRequestAPI);
                } else {
                    runRequestAPI();
                }
            } else {
                runRequestAPI();
            }
        } else {
            runRequestAPI();
        }
    }

    private void runRequestAPI() {
        // Remote URL
        String string = Config.ACCESS_KEY;
        // Drive URL
        String string1 = string.replace("https://", "").replace("http://", "");
        // Data
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList(string1.split("/"));
        // Drive ID
        String string2 = list.get(3);
        callbackConfigCall = RestAdapter.createApiGoogleDrive().getDriveJsonFileId(string2);
        Log.d(TAG, "Requesting API from Google Drive Share link");
        Log.d(TAG, "Google drive file id : " + list.get(3));

        callbackConfigCall.enqueue(new Callback<CallbackConfig>() {
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<CallbackConfig> call, @NonNull Response<CallbackConfig> response) {
                // Response
                CallbackConfig callbackConfig = response.body();
                runDisplayAPIResults(callbackConfig);
            }

            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<CallbackConfig> call, @NonNull Throwable th) {
                Log.e(TAG, "initialize failed");
                runActivityMain();
            }
        });
    }

    private void runDisplayAPIResults(CallbackConfig resp) {
        if (resp != null) {
            app = resp.app;
            ads = resp.ads;
            blog = resp.blog;
            labels = resp.labels;

            if (app.status.equals("1")) {
                preferenceShared.saveBlogCredentials(blog.blogger_id, blog.api_key);
                utilityAdsManager.saveConfig(preferenceShared, app);
                utilityAdsManager.saveAds(preferenceAds, ads);

                if (app.custom_label_list.equals("true")) {
                    databaseCategory.truncateTableCategory(DatabaseCategory.TABLE_LABEL);
                    databaseCategory.addListCategory(labels, DatabaseCategory.TABLE_LABEL);
                    runActivityMain();
                } else {
                    runRequestCategory();
                }

                Log.d(TAG, "App status is live");
            } else {
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(app.redirect_url)));

                finish();
                Log.d(TAG, "App status is suspended");
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "initialize success");
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "initialize failed");
            runActivityMain();
        }
    }

    private void runRequestCategory() {
        this.callbackLabelCall = RestAdapter.createApiCategory(preferenceShared.getBloggerId()).getLabel();
        this.callbackLabelCall.enqueue(new Callback<CallbackCategory>() {
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<CallbackCategory> call, @NonNull Response<CallbackCategory> response) {
                CallbackCategory resp = response.body();
                if (resp == null) {
                    runActivityMain();
                    return;
                }

                databaseCategory.truncateTableCategory(DatabaseCategory.TABLE_LABEL);
                databaseCategory.addListCategory(resp.feed.category, DatabaseCategory.TABLE_LABEL);
                runActivityMain();

                Log.d(TAG, "Success initialize label with count " + resp.feed.category.size() + " items");
            }

            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<CallbackCategory> call, @NonNull Throwable th) {
                Log.e("onFailure", th.getMessage());
                if (!call.isCanceled()) {
                    runActivityMain();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void runActivityMain() {
        new Handler().postDelayed(() -> {
            this.finish();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityMain.class);

            startActivity(intent);
        }, DELAY_SPLASH);
    }
}
```

The playstore crashes report as following. java.lang.NullPointerException:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.xxx.xxx, PID: 19603
> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
> com.xxx.xxx.activities.ActivitySplash$a.b(ActivitySplash.java:8)
> at com.google.android.exoplayer2.audio.i.run(R8$$SyntheticClass:8)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)  at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)   at
> android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)   at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)     at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)    at
> com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)